# How to select the 2nd result with jQuery?

Tags: jquery

```
$('select')
```

I want to select the second `select` above,how to do it?

Answer (score 5):

You can do it like this: `$('select').eq(1)` or `$('select:eq(1)')`

Comment: @Jason - that will return third element because the eq selector is zero based.

Comment: FYI using non-browser standard selectors like `:eq()`, `:not()`, etc... is slow... as much as possible, use the methods like `.eq()`, `.not()`...